# JPA как обновить сущности в БД не по ключевому полю?

Tags: java, jpa

Имеется сущность:

```
@Entity
public class Category {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;
    String name;
    Long companyId;
}
```

Также имеется репозиторий c методом saveAll:

```
@Override
public List<Category> saveAll(List<Category> categories) {
    List<Category> categoriesInRepoCategories = new ArrayList<>();
    categoryRepository.saveAll(categories).forEach(categoriesInRepoCategories::add);
    return categoriesInRepoCategories;
}
```

Проблема собственно вот в чем, список категорий я каждый раз получаю парсингом с сайта, соответственно мне не известны `id`, и при вызове `saveAll` у меня в базу дублируются записи. Я так понимаю решения из коробки по данному случае нету? И придется изначально извлекать все записи из БД, сопоставлять их по имени  с теми что вернул парсер (проставлять существующим id) и записывать полученные данные в БД, или все же можно как-то пометить поле `name`?

В итоге добавил такой метод:

```
public List<Category> upsertAll(List<Category> categories) {
    List<Category> categoriesInRepoCategories = findAll();
    categories.forEach(c -> {
        Long id = categoriesInRepoCategories.stream().filter(cc -> cc.getName().equals(c.getName())).findAny().orElse(c).getId();
        c.setId(id);
    });
    return saveAll(categories);
}
```

Comment: Просто в качестве первичного ключа выберите не id, а какое-нибудь уникальное поле из класса Category

Comment: у меня получается уникальным `name` но как-то не хочется строить связи один-ко-многим по строковому ключу `name`. Мой вариант сохранения данных в бд считается не красивым?

Comment: Обычно у списочных элементов на сайте есть какой-то уникальный идентификатор, поэтому есть смысл в том, чтобы его тоже сохранять и использовать в качестве PK

Answer (score 0):

Spring в методе `save()` использует следующую логику. Если у сущности есть `id`, то вызывается метод `update()`, если `id` отсутствует то вызывается `save()`.

Соответственно теперь вам нужно реализовать эту логику самому.

Почему не аннотировали `name` - `@Column(unique=true)`, если дубли не должны попадать?

Comment: `@Column(unique=true)` на данном этапе не принципиально, но получу исключение, в общем видимо придется как я писал выше, извлекать все записи из БД сопоставлять по имени и только потом вызывать `saveAll`